# How to use REGEX to validate EditText?

Tags: java, android

I want to validate a username against these requirements:

1. Just accept character or digital
2. At least one character

I tried with

```
 public boolean validateFormat(String input){

        return Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9]+$").matcher(input).matches();   
 }
```

How can I do this one?

Comment: Why do you consider `_` in it? Does your code has problem?

Comment: I do not know about "_" as I refer from other website.

Comment: If you use underscore, it is acceptable for input string. By using "^[A-Za-z0-9]+$", there is no problem and should work well as your requirement.

Comment: It is usually helpful when asking regex questions to present a representative list of valid and invalid strings as test data to help explain your requirements.  So as an example from your text I'd say a username of "1234" is invalid (it doesn't contain at least one "character") but your regex would allow that (which I think Amit's answer addresses?).

Answer (score 1):

Try with this regex:

```
^(\w|\d)+$
```

`^` indicates the start of the string

`$` indicates the end of the string

`\w` means any word character

`\d` means any digit

`|` is the logical OR operator

Anyway, i suggest you to use an online regex tester like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) .It is very helpful to quickly test regular expressions.

Hope it can help!

**== UPDATE ==**

In Java code:

```
final String regex = "^(\\w|\\d)+$";
final String string = "myCoolUsername12";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if(matcher.matches()) {
   // if you are interested only in matching the full regex
}

// Otherwise, you can iterate over the matched groups (including the full match)
while (matcher.find()) { 
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! I got error when I used your code. The error pointed that "illegal escape character in string literal"

Comment: thank you! The code should be "^(\\w|\\d)" but cannot reach my required for "At least one character".

Comment: What i've typed is the regular expression, not the actual java code. It is obvious that you should add the escape characters. Anyway, the "^(\\w|\\d)" regex is not correct because you've removed the + that mean "at least one or more". The correct one, including the escape characters, is: ^(\\w|\\d)+$ . Please see the updated answer for the java code.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ _-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/
```